# Why use an entity manager?

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence

I am using Hibernate to map objects to entities and I have started to use an Entity Manager. This might be a silly question but what actually is the reason for using the entity manager? Previously I would have used a HibernateSessionFactory to get a session and then use that session to pull/push data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the `EntityManager` is part of the standard - JPA. Theoretically, you can switch implementations (Hibernate, EclipseLink, OpenJPA) if you need to. Apart from alleged portability there isn't such a big difference between the two.

Hibernate implements the JPA standard. In fact, the `EntityManager` has a delegate, based on the concrete implementation. For Hibernate the delegate is the `Session`. If you call `getDelegate()` it will return the current `Session`.

I've always used hibernate with JPA (EntityManager) and had very rarely had the need to obtain the Session.

Answer (score 2):

EntityManager is a concept of JPA.
You dont need to use JPA with Hibernate at all (in fact, if it's JPA1, I would suggest you dont).

Answer (score 1):

You use an EntityManager when you are using JPA API. Hibernate implementation of `EntityManager` internally calls `HibernateSessionFactory` and manages Hibernate sessions for you.

EntityManagers in JPA serve basically the same purpose as Hibernate sessions.